# Load response data one after other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a response which looks like this

```
<li class="dt">
<div>
<a><img src="imgpath1"><a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="dt">
<div>
<a><img src="imgpath2"><a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="dt">
<div>
<a><img src="imgpath3"><a>
</div>
</li>
```

What I am doing I my ajax success

```
sucess:function(data){
$(#MAIN_UL).html(data)
}
```

What I want is this [Fade in each element - one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379900/fade-in-each-element-one-after-another)

I even tried loading the entire response first and giving it a display none and then making it appear.But dint work.

how do I use this response,how do I make the li in my response appear one by one after delay?The problem occurs when i have to do it with my response..otherwise it works fine on data which comes on page load.

Comment: And please use "done" instead of "success" as it's been deprecated as of 1.8

Comment: @LShetty - The `jqXHR.success()` function was deprecated, not the `success` callback setting of the `$.ajax()` function.

Comment: @John, The jQuery.ajax() function is basically just one big jqXHR object. Hence what I mentioned above is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
success: function(html) {
    var $items = $(html).hide(); // First hide all the li elements
    $('#MAIN_UL').html($items); // Add the li elements to the page

    // Fade-in the li elements one at a time
    (function showItem(i) {
        $items.eq(i).fadeIn('slow', function() {
              showItem(i + 1);
        });
    })(0);
}
```

The `.fadeIn()` function takes a callback that executes when the animation is complete. This can be used to cause the elements to fade-in one after another. The `.eq()` function is used to move through the elements one at a time.

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeUW8/1/)

Comment: why $items and $(html) ? i tried this but it gives me an error..unrecognized error
What I am doing now is $('#MAIN_UL').html(data);

Comment: @Digital_at_heart - I renamed the parameter from `data` to `html`. `$(html)` creates the elements without attaching them to the DOM so they can be hidden first. `$items` is needed to fade them in.

Comment: @Digital_at_heart - Do you mean you are getting `Syntax Error, unrecognized expression`. If so, the html returned by your ajax call may not be quite valid, so the call to `$(html)` fails, but [this does not](http://jsfiddle.net/7V835/). You should fix the html though if it is invalid.