# How to get the same function to execute for each element of the same class one after the other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one outer box and an inner box and there are some identical boxes with the same class names inside the second box. I want all of these boxes to appear one after the other with this fade-in effect. So far I have done it for the outer and inner div, and I wanted to use the same function for all the identical boxes inside. I tried to do the same for outer and inner div since they too just need the exact same function. But I wasn't successful. Here is my code :

html:

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```js
let div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0];
let div2 = document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[0];
let div3 = document.getElementsByClassName("div3");

div1.style.visibility = "hidden";
div2.style.visibility = "hidden";

function first() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            div1.style.animation = "fadein 5s";
            div1.style.visibility = "visible";
            resolve("div1 worked!");
        }, 1000);
    });
}
function second() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            div2.style.animation = "fadein 5s";
            div2.style.visibility = "visible";
            resolve("div2 worked!");
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function abc(element) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            element.style.animation = "fadein 5s";
            element.style.visibility = "visible";
            resolve("third");
        }, 1000);
    });
}

first()
    .then(second)
    .then((div3) => {
        div3.forEach((element) => {
            abc(element);
        });
    });
```

css

```css
.div1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.div2 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
}
.div3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 10px;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The first two works and I don't know how I can reuse the function for the remaining div3 class divs. I tried to reuse the function for the first two as well, but it didn't work and ended up writing same functions again and again. I want to call function `abc` for each element in `div3` and only execute the next one after the first element is done - like how it executes for first and second but using the same function. Not sure how to do that and I'm stuck. Here is a codepen [link](https://codepen.io/akhilalekha/pen/zYKrmWX). As of now all the div3 divs appear together with the second div.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790474/jquery-fadein-children-elements-of-different-element-types-sequentially

Comment: animation-delay may help you - you use the same animation name on all the elements but delay them starting their animations by different amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loops` and `animation-delay` to apply the animation as per your need. The following code will work for this case. Code is full with comments to explain what is happening at each point. I have also slightly modified the css so that we don't get any weird blinking effect while executing the code.

```js
//Declare all the classes - 
let divs = ["div1", "div2", "div3"];

//Initiate a delay for each iteration
let delay = 0;

//Run a loop for each class
for(let i = 0; i<divs.length; i++){
  
  //Get the element
  let div = document.getElementsByClassName(divs[i]);
  
  //Run a loop for element with the class
  //(We only have one div with the classes div1 and div2. So it will run one time for them.
  //We have 5 divs with div3 class. It will run 5 times in that case 
  for(let j = 0; j<div.length; j++){
    
    //Get the individual element and add animation with delay
    //The delay will also ensure that the animation starts only when the previous element has finished the animation
    div[j].style.animation = `fadein 5s ${delay}s forwards` ;
    div[j].classList.add("show");
    
    //Increase delay with every iteration
    delay+=5;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.div1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
.div3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}

.show {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">1</div>
    <div class="div3">2</div>
    <div class="div3">3</div>
    <div class="div3">4</div>
    <div class="div3">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The script may seem very long but it is only 10 lines long without the comments. This will also work if you increase or decrease the number of `divs`

Comment: Thank you :) I forgot about the animation delay property!!

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to solve the problem using `setInterval` for executing a piece of code every x seconds.

The function **fadeIn** takes an array of elements that will be faded in by adding the class "show" (se details for "show" in CSS-code below). This will animate the given elements.

The function **start** collects the elements that will be faded and fades in the first collection of element, then countinuesly fades in the rest of the elements in the array "elements" every 3 seconds.

```js
function fadeIn(el) {
  // For every element in the collection
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    // Add the class "show"
    el[i].classList.add('show');
  }
}

function start() {
  /*
    Collects all the elements that we want to fadeIn in order. First collection of elements will be animated firstly, second collection of elements will be animated secondly, etc.
  */
  var elements = [];
  elements.push(document.getElementsByClassName("div1"));
  elements.push(document.getElementsByClassName("div2"));
  elements.push(document.getElementsByClassName("div3"));
  
  // Show the first collection of elements
  fadeIn(elements[0]);
  
  // Show the rest of the element collections in array "elements"
  var i = 1;
  fadeInInterval = setInterval(function() {
    fadeIn(elements[i]);
    // If there is no more collections to fade in, end the setInterval
    if (i == elements.length-1) {
      clearInterval(fadeInInterval)
    }
    i++
  }, 3000) // Every 3 seconds
}

start();
```

```css
div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.div1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
.div3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}

.show {
  animation: fadein 5s;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```