# Call a function, passed to another function as an argument, on a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing

I was using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661858/3806231) from another Stack Overflow post to have multiple elements fade in one at a time using the `fadeIn` method and fade out in reverse using `fadeOut`. For example, using `fadeIn`:

```
$("#container").children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400 * index).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Since I would be using the code multiple times and with different animations, I put it into a function, where the jQuery object to iterate over, delay and animation to perform are passed as arguments:

```
function animateOneByOne(elements, delay, animation) {
    elements.each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(delay*index).animation();
    });
}
```

called using something like:

```
animateOneByOne($("#introelements").children(), 400, function() { fadeIn(300); });
```

**I've now realised this doesn't work because there is no `animation` function inside the `$(...).delay(...)` object.**

Is there a nice way of putting this code into a function?

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I found a simple solution, in which I changed the function passed as an argument to have the single element as a parameter:

```
function animateOneByOne(elements, delay, animation) {
    elements.each(function(index) {
        animation($(this).delay(delay * index));
    });
}
```

called using something like:

```
animateOneByOne($("#introelements").children(), 400, function(element) { element.fadeIn(300); });
```

(I've posted this in case anyone else had a similar problem and in case there are any better solutions.)